# How to use API of Jenkins in an Active Choices plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I use a lot `[Active choices plugin][1]`
With a Groovy script I can build dynamically the drop-down list.
With the script console of Jenkins, I can evaluate:

```
User.getAll()
```

But in an active choices plugin, it fails and I don't know why (no error message, no logs).

How can I use the Groovy Jenkins API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are prohibited from performing some actions by the Jenkins groovy sandbox, such as making rest calls and do dynamic introspection. I would advise you to bake some curl calls and execute them inside a jenkins sh call, or define a client using Python.

Having said that, here's a working example of how to define a rest api request and fill an active choices plugin list is as follows:

```html
def url = "https://myfancyapi/v1/users/"
def get = new URL(url).openConnection();
def getRC = get.getResponseCode();
if (getRC.equals(200)) {
    def result = get.getInputStream().getText()
    def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper() 
    return jsonSlurper.parseText(result)
}else{
    return []
}
```

Comment: It is a pity I cannot use the APIs for security reasons, I don't care about.

Comment: @david.perez if you don't mind security, you can call you api using this code, assuming it doesn't use any kind of authentication